# Concatenate multiple columns into a list in a single column

Tags: python, python-polars

I'd like to combine multiple columns as a list into a single column.

For example, this data frame:

```
┌─────┬─────┐
│ a   ┆ b   │
│ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╡
│ 1   ┆ 4   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2   ┆ 5   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3   ┆ 6   │
└─────┴─────┘
```

into this one:

```
┌────────────┐
│ combine    │
│ ---        │
│ list [i64] │
╞════════════╡
│ [1, 4]     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ [2, 5]     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ [3, 6]     │
└────────────┘
```

Right now I'm doing it this way:

```py
df = df.with_column(pl.map(['a','b'],lambda df:pl.Series(np.column_stack([df[0].to_numpy(),df[1].to_numpy()]).tolist())).alias('combine'))
```

Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: I will add a new expression that allows to convert `[1, 2, 3]` to `[[1], [2], [3]]`. Then we can use `pl.concat_list` to concat them.

Comment: Cool ty for the great support :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the landing of [this PR](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/pull/1888), we can `reshape` a `Series/Expr` into a `Series/Expr` of type `List`. These can then be `concatenated` per row.

```py
df = pl.DataFrame({
    "a": [1, 2, 3],
    "b": [4, 5, 6]
})


df.select([
    pl.concat_list([
        pl.col("a").reshape((-1, 1)), 
        pl.col("b").reshape((-1, 1))
    ])
])
```

Outputs:

```
shape: (3, 1)
┌────────────┐
│ a          │
│ ---        │
│ list [i64] │
╞════════════╡
│ [1, 4]     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ [2, 5]     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ [3, 6]     │
└────────────┘
```

Note that we give the shape `(-1, 1)`, where `-1` means infer the dimension size. So this reads as `(infer the rows, 1 column)`.

You can compile polars from source to use this new feature, or wait a few days and then its landed on PyPi.

Comment: Ty for the update! I've got some question regarding the datatype Object, right now the support of this datatype is very limited and many operations doesn't work well, will this change in future, or is this a limitation trough apache arrow?

Comment: Latest release expanded the (experimental) support. They can now be used in expressions. However, if you can you must always prefer native types.

Answer (score 2):

In modern polars, [`pl.concat_list`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.concat_list.html) can be used directly (without the need to reshape any columns).

```py
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame({
    "a": [1, 2, 3],
    "b": [4, 5, 6],
})
```

```py
df.select(pl.concat_list("a", "b", 2 * pl.col("b")))
```

```
shape: (3, 1)
┌────────────┐
│ a          │
│ ---        │
│ list[i64]  │
╞════════════╡
│ [1, 4, 8]  │
│ [2, 5, 10] │
│ [3, 6, 12] │
└────────────┘
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df.apply(list, axis=1)
```

Here you can see an example:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [4, 5, 6]})
>>> df
   a  b
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  6
>>> df.apply(list, axis=1)
0    [1, 4]
1    [2, 5]
2    [3, 6]
```

Comment: I'm looking for a way to do it in polars

Comment: FWIW The `pl.List` dtype in Polars is very different from a column of Python lists. 
The `pl.List` dtype is actually a column where each row is a Polars Series and the Series has the same dtype in each row.